# node js 'FILE_NOT_FOUND'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so I am learning node JS and trying to make a discord bot with it and I am having troubles.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "gabe",
    description: "gabe",
    execute(message, args) {
        var fs = require("fs");
        var files = fs.readdirSync("./gabe/");
        let chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];
        const fileDirectory = "./gabe/";
        const filePicture = fileDirectory.concat(chosenFile);
        message.channel.send({ files: filePicture });
    },
};
```

I am trying to select a random picture from a folder (./gabe/), but I am getting 'FILE_NOT_FOUND'

In my code I am randomly selecting a .png from the ./gabe/ folder and trying to concat it to make it './gabe/name.png' so that the discord bot can dipsplay it.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the directory in which the script in question resides? Are you sure `gabe/` is a subdirectory of it?

Comment: @esqew sorry, new to posting. I added it to the main body. When I call the function just using a preset string it works, like if it was './gabe/test.png'. But the problem is when I am trying to randomize what picture I get and getting the string to work. So it starts from Documents/discordbot and /gabe is a folder inside it

Comment: "*So it starts from Documents/discordbot*" I'm not seeing any reference to such a directory in your code, can you clarify? By "directory structure", I expected to see a representation of how the first two or three levels of your project's file and folder structure appear in the filesystem; can you please add that for further clarity?

Comment: @esqew It starts directly in the discord bot folder. So if I had the pngs in the discord bot folder it could read it directly from there as ./test.png. Before I had this stuff hard coded and it worked. Sorry if I am misunderstanding your question but when it checks for files it starts at /discordbot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`filePicture` is a string. The `files` argument in `message.channel.send` requires an array of actual Buffers or such.

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks!